# Add an array to a session array

Tags: arrays, session, array-push

I have an array from a MySQL query of ID numbers that I'm trying to add to a Session Array that is already created.  For some reason, my code is adding an array inside the Session Array already in place rather than just adding the ID numbers to the Session.  What is causing this to happen?

Here is my PHP...

```
//Find members of this group and create an array to add to cart
            $deletedgroupmembersquery = "SELECT * FROM groupmember WHERE group_id='$groupid'";
            $deletedgroupmembers = mysql_query($deletedgroupmembersquery) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysql_error());

            if (mysql_num_rows($deletedgroupmembers) > 0) {
                $groupmembers = mysql_num_rows($deletedgroupmembers);
                $cart = array();
                while(($deletedmembersrow =  mysql_fetch_assoc($deletedgroupmembers))) {
                    $cart[] = $deletedmembersrow['contact_id'];
                }

                    //Add the array to the cart session
                    if (isset($cart)) {
                    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
                    array_push($_SESSION[cart],$cart);
                    } else {
                    }
```

Here is the session the above code is creating..

```
Array ( [cart] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1362 [1] => 1371 [2] => 2241 ) )
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

`$cart` is already an array. When you do:

```
array_push($_SESSION[cart],$cart);
```

you're pushing it as a sub-array of `$_SESSION['cart']`. I think you just want:

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
```

Comment: Like the other answer, wouldn't this replace the cart session that is already in place?  How can I add the values in $cart to the session array already in place?

Comment: Why did you do `$_SESSION['cart'] = array();` if you didn't want to replace the cart that's already in place?

Answer (score 0):

You're defining $cart as an array before you push it into $_SESSION[cart]...so you're pushing an array into an array.  Try something like this:

```
if (!empty($cart)) {
  $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
  foreach ($cart AS $item) {
    array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $item);
  }
}
```

You can also just place the array_push inside your while(), and stick the $_SESSION['cart'] = array() before the while(), and it will achieve the same thing.

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly, except that it replaced the array that was already in place.  How can I add the array to the values that are in the cart array already in place?

Comment: If $_SESSION['cart'] already has values inside it, remove the $_SESSION['cart'] = array() line.  That's just overriding whatever it might already be with an empty array.

array_push will push new elements onto the end of an array, regardless of what might already be in the array.